# Can pretty variable names be used for registers in GCC inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have some inline assembly. I want GCC to have total freedom in choosing GP registers to allocate. I also want to use pretty names for registers inside the assembly for ease of comprehension for future maintainers. I think I did this previously (10+ years ago) for ARM 5te but am now scratching my head while writing some AArch64 code.

In a simpler example, this is what I want:

```
uint32_t arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2, result;

asm volatile(
  "add  %result, %arg1, %arg2\n"
  // Outputs:
  : ???
  // Inputs:
  : ???
  // Clobbered:
  : ???
);
```

I figure I need the right voodoo to go where I have written **"???"** above.

Is it possible?

Comment: As a follow-up, I did some benchmarking of a real example and disassembled (android ndk objdump) it to see the final result. The example had four lines of actual assembly code. It used a fake output to give a pretty name to a temporary register and let gcc choose any register it wanted to use for that temporary. It was slower than expected and the disassembly showed excess crud above and below the four lines. It was a lot faster and there was less crud in a version that hard-coded the registers and clobbered the temporary, even though that gave gcc a register allocation constraint to deal with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
[arg1] "r" (arg1)
```

For example. The two names(`[arg1]` and `(arg1)` above) can be different.

Inside the assembly code, you'd use:

```
add %[result], %[arg1], %[arg2]
```

[Documentation link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands).

Here's your whole example reworked (case changed for the assembly variables just to illustrate that they needn't be the same):

```
uint32_t arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2, result;

asm volatile(
  "add  %[RESULT], %[ARG1], %[ARG2]\n"
  : [RESULT]"=r"(result)             /* output */
  : [ARG1]"r"(arg1), [ARG2]"r"(arg2) /* inputs */
  :                                  /* no clobbers */
);
```